# In LokiJS, Creating multiple Databases or Creating multiple collection with in database, which will have better performance

Tags: lokijs

I am using LokiJS in Node Express Web Application.

Use case is as follows

1. For every request on Node JS, I will bring the data from SOLR and insert into LokiJS Database.
2. Create some dynamic views in in-memory LokiJS DB
3. Update records in dynamic views
4. Perform count of records in dynamic views

This Node JS Web Application will be multi user application. And there could be multiple request from different users performing above Use Case in the application.

For this scenario, Creating a New In-memory DB for every request will have better performance or creating a new collection for every request will have better performance.

> I do not need performance statistics, but only an idea to the correctness of approach.

Comment: i don`t know what you are trying to do but LokiJS  is for the client side, you don`t need it in the server side. i think the way you try to achieve your task is wrong. what are you trying to do?

Comment: Intent of using LokiJS is to avoid looping (for aggregating data and finding data with specific Ids) over records in Node JS Code. With the help of LokiJS dynamic views, and map reduce functions I am planning to perform aggregation quickly without performing these CPU intensive operations in Node JS